# OS X: Is it possible to view the source code of the Standard C Library?

Tags: c, macos, c-standard-library

I'd like to examine the code.  I've searched my Mac, Stack Overflow, and the internet but I can't find the answer.  Perhaps they don't place this code on a Mac.  Can anyone set me straight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Right here!](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/) That's for 10.8.3. You can find the source code for other versions of OS X or iOS, or other packages, [here](http://opensource.apple.com).

Comment: Thx mip.  I guess that I should have realized that Apple wouldn't put the source on everyone's mac.